# Bootstrap - designing a good header / navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making my own website and faced a problem with appearance on mobile.
Here's a picture of header code and how it looks like on PC:
[image]

And here's it on mobile:
[image]
CSS code is there too:
[image]

Do you guys have any ideas how to make logo and text scale with device's screen so I position it and it looks good?

**EDIT:** CSS and HTML code as requested:

```css
#logo {
 margin-top: -10px;
 max-width: 125px;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: "arcadepix";
    src: url("../fonts/Arcadepix Plus.woff") format('woff');
}
#header {
 z-index: 10;
 padding-top: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 background-color: #fffddc;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 18px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.67);
 -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 18px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.67);
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 18px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.67);
 border-bottom: 3px #867b99 dotted;
}
#head {
 z-index: 10;
 color: black!important;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0px 0px 50px;
 -moz-border-image: url(../img/border.png) 50 0 round repeat;
 -webkit-border-image: url(../img/border.png) 50 0 round repeat;
 -o-border-image: url(../img/border.png) 50 0 round repeat;
 border-image: url(../img/border.png) 50 0 fill round repeat;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   
   <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" id="header">
    <img id="logo" src="img/!bones.png"><span style="margin-left: 20px;font-family: arcadepix!important;font-size:2.750em;color:#6b627a;">Fishbones</span></img>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" id="head"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the HTML and CSS to the question as text, not as screen captures.

Comment: Please post a working example of the code (HTML/CSS/JS) related to your question in a Snippet. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `img` is self closing tag we can't put `span` inside the `img` tag

Comment: @Amitsingh works fine however.

Comment: It may well work fine but it's not allowed in the specification @LexLaiden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use media queries to change the size of your font once the viewport is under 360px; see example, as once the viewport is under 360px, then 320px the body color will change to as to represent when the font will re-size.

*I also moved your inline style into the stylesheet.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "arcadepix";
  src: url("../fonts/Arcadepix Plus.woff") format('woff');
}
#logo {
  margin-top: -10px;
  max-width: 125px;
}
.fish-text {
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-family: 'Arcadepix';
  font-size: 2.750em;
  color: #6b627a;
}
#header {
  z-index: 10;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: #fffddc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 18px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.67);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 18px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.67);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 18px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.67);
  border-bottom: 3px #867b99 dotted;
}
#head {
  z-index: 10;
  color: black!important;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 0px 50px;
  -moz-border-image: url(../img/border.png) 50 0 round repeat;
  -webkit-border-image: url(../img/border.png) 50 0 round repeat;
  -o-border-image: url(../img/border.png) 50 0 round repeat;
  border-image: url(../img/border.png) 50 0 fill round repeat;
}
@media (max-width: 360px) {
  body {
    background: red;
  }
  #header {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .fish-text {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 300px) {
  body {
    background: lightblue;
  }
  .fish-text {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" id="header">
        <img id="logo" src="http://placehold.it/150x40/f00/fff?text=FISH" /><span class="fish-text">Fishbones</span>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" id="head"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Good, but how do I center it once it reaches red state?

https://i.gyazo.com/45e550804303056a3fe873b4807c185f.png

Answer (score 0):

At first there are some points to be noted

1. The `img` is self closing tag. so we can't put the `span tag inside.
2. To make the page responsive we have to use those classes which bootstrap has provided.
3. You should use `col-xs-10` and `col-xs-offset-2` for mobile devices
4. And in `bootstrap` one `row` contains `12` column not `11`.

Check my snippet the image is responsive in mobile device.

```css
#logo {
  margin-top: -10px;
  max-width: 125px;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "arcadepix";
  src: url("../fonts/Arcadepix Plus.woff") format('woff');
}
#header {
  z-index: 10;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: #fffddc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 18px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.67);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 18px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.67);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 18px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.67);
  border-bottom: 3px #867b99 dotted;
}
#head {
  z-index: 10;
  color: black!important;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 0px 50px;
  -moz-border-image: url(../img/border.png) 50 0 round repeat;
  -webkit-border-image: url(../img/border.png) 50 0 round repeat;
  -o-border-image: url(../img/border.png) 50 0 round repeat;
  border-image: url(../img/border.png) 50 0 fill round repeat;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-2" id="header">
        <img id="logo" src="img/!bones.png" /><span style="margin-left: 20px;font-family: arcadepix!important;font-size:2.750em;color:#6b627a;">Fishbones</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-2" id="head"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Now the header is off and it still doesn't work.

https://gyazo.com/1956739045e3518ddc5faf88935a45cc
https://gyazo.com/699f2a22e5029489a1232d7fce90b5a8

Comment: what are you trying to say that header is off i can't get you

Comment: It's supposed to be centered

Comment: you can use `text-align` class in your container